# How to change quality labels to 1080p in Jwplayer v8?

Tags: jwplayer

I don't understand that my m3u8 file displays 800p on jwplayer while it is 1080p, after some research I saw that jwplayer bases their quality on the height, example 1920x800, they will take 800p, so I I was wondering if there was a way to change it? I want it to display 1080p and not 800p. [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rdXo.png)

I have already tried to do the Quality Labels of Jwplayer but it does not change and gives this kind of result.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJL35.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YuE1.png)